# Prove that $\lim_{x \to 2} 5x^2 = 20$ using $\epsilon - \delta$ definition.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, logic, proof-explanation, epsilon-delta

Working on the book: Richard Hammack. "*Book of Proof*" (p. 259)

> **Example 13.2** Prove that $\lim_{x \to 2} 5x^2 = 20$.

> Proof. Suppose $\epsilon$ > 0. Notice that
> $$
> | f(x) - L| = |5x^2 - 20| = |5(x^2 - 4)| = |5(x - 2)(x + 2)| = 5 · |x-2| · |x + 2|.
> $$
> Now we have a factor of $|x-2|$ in $|f(x)-L|$, but it is accompanied with $|x+2|$. But if $|x-2|$ is small, then $x$ is close to 2, so $|x+2|$ should be close to 4.

Now, the author assumes $|x-2| \leq 1$

> In fact, if $|x-2| \leq 1$, then |$x+2| = |(x-2)+4| \leq |x-2|+|4| \leq 1+4 = 5$. (Here we applied the inequality (13.2) from page 245.) In other words, if $|x - 2| \leq 1, \text{then } |x + 2| \leq 5$, and the above equation yields

> $$
> | f (x) - L| = |5x^2 - 20| = 5 · |x - 2| · |x + 2| < 5 · |x - 2| · 5 = 25|x - 2|.
> $$
> Take $\delta$ to be smaller than both 1 and $\frac{\epsilon}{25}$ . Then $0<|x-2|<\delta$ implies $|5x^2-20|<25·|x-2|<25\delta<25\frac{\epsilon}{25}=\epsilon$. By Definition 13.2, $\lim_{x \to 2} 5x^2 = 20$

My questions are:

- Where does the assumption $|x-2| \leq 1$ come from and how it gets discharged ?
- I wonder if the author is really proving $\forall \epsilon > 0 ( \exists \delta > 0(|x-c| < \delta \Rightarrow (|x-c| \leq 1 \Rightarrow |f(x) - f(c)| < \epsilon)))$. Perhaps, I am wrong but it is not possible to add that assumption as a premise, as arbitrary variable $x$ appears after the introduction of $\delta$.

Comment: The author is saying that it would be nice if you could assume $\lvert x - 2 \rvert \le 1$, and then the author makes this the case by picking $\delta$ to be smaller than $1$. Remember, in a limit proof you're given $\epsilon$, but you have the free will to choose $\delta$! Also my compliments on your very clearly stated and typeset question.

Comment: If you like, the author shows that $\forall \epsilon > 0, \delta = \tfrac 12 \min\{1, \tfrac 1{25} \epsilon\} \implies (\lvert x - c \rvert < \delta \implies \lvert f(x) - f(c) \rvert < \epsilon)$, which is a sufficient condition for the full definition of a limit.

Comment: Thank you, @IzaakvanDongen ! In your last comment, are you multiplying $1\2$ by min ? Could you explain where does that come from ?

Comment: Not to worry! I just put that in there because I was being a bit lazy. I saw that your author wanted $\delta$ to be *smaller* than both, which I know $\tfrac 12 \min\{\dots\}$ is. I didn't check if the proof also works if $\delta$ is less than or equal to both. If that's the case, the author has also proved my statement without the $\tfrac 12$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author is looking for a $\delta > 0$ for which $|x - 2| < \delta \Rightarrow |x^2 - 25| < \epsilon$. If some $\delta$ works, then a smaller $\delta$ works as well and by assuming $|x - 2| < 1$ the author is looking for a $\delta$ that is at most $1$.

That is what he is saying with "Take $\delta$ to be smaller than both $1$ and $\epsilon/25$".

To explicitly answer your first question: the author claims "if $|x - 2| \leq 1$, then $|x + 2| \leq 5$ and ... $|f(x) - L| \leq 25|x-2|$", so the assumption $|x - 2| \leq 1$ is discharged right there; in the next sentence that is already not assumed anymore.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Magdirag ! I think I'm starting to understand. When the author says "Take $\epsilon$ to be smaller than both 1 and  $\epsilon/25$", does he really mean "...and $\delta = \epsilon/25$". My question comes from the fact that he performs a substitution in the last line of the proof.

Comment: Is discharging accomplished by the rule of Conditional Introduction ? I think that section of the proof could be: 
$
\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
$
$$
\fitch{}{
  \text{Let }d = \frac{\epsilon}{25} \land \delta <=1\\
  \fitch{0 < |x-2|<\delta}{
   \fitch{|x-2| \leq 1}{
     \vdots\\
     |x+2|\leq 5
     
}\\
      |x-2| \leq 1 \to |x+2|\leq 5\\
      |x-2| \leq 1\\
      |x+2|\leq5\\
      \vdots
}
}
$$
Is this correct ?

Comment: No, he doesn't mean $\delta = \epsilon/25$. The reasoning must work for all $\epsilon$, but if you take $\delta = \epsilon/25$, then the reasoning doesn't work for $\epsilon \geq 25$. Of course, it is sufficient to prove the claim for sufficiently small $\epsilon$, but that is not the route the author has chosen to go.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Magdiragdag ! Took a little to digest but I think I got it. We have $25|x-2|<25\delta$ and multiplying the inequality $d<e/25$ by 25, we get $25\delta<\epsilon$. Combining those equalities, $25\delta<\epsilon$. Is that correct ?

Answer (score 3):

As we look for the limit when $ x $ goes to $ x=2 $, we can assume that $ x $ is not far from $ 2 $, let say
$$|x-2|<a \; or\;  2-a<x<2+a\; $$
$$or\; -4-a<4-a<x+2<4+a$$

$$or \; |x+2|<4+a$$

with $ a>0$.

with this additional condition, given $\epsilon>0$, we look for $ \delta>0$ such that

$$|x-2|<a \; and\; |x-2|<\delta \implies$$
$$5 |x-2||x+2|<\epsilon$$

but
$$5|x-2||x+2|<5(a+4)|x-2|$$

So, we just need to satisfy the condition
$$|x-2|<\frac{\epsilon}{5(a+4)}$$

Thus, you just need that
$$\delta=\min(a,\frac{\epsilon}{5(a+4)}).$$

The author prefered to choose $ a=1$

If you decide to take $ a=\frac 13$, you will choose
$$\delta=\min(\frac 13,\frac{\epsilon}{5(\frac 13+4)})$$

Comment: Thank you, @hamam_Abdallah. Did you reached a result equivalent to $\epsilon/25$ with your proof ?

Comment: @F.Zer Yes, if you take $ a=1$.